# Java - Determine event sequence - AB or BA

Tags: java, sequence

this one might sound trivial question but I am not able to arrive at a proper solution. Request for help.

Problem : In my code, I get 2 events (one after the other) in a sequence. The sequence could be "event A" first then "event B" or vice versa. If my event sequence is AB then I need to take some action and similarly if my sequence is BA, then I need to take another action.
However, I am finding it tough to determine the sequence and set a boolean value. 
One solution I have thought of is to use stack. Both these events will be pushed to stack. I will check if my stack size is 2, then I will pop the last value and see which event it is. If it is A, then i will add logic for BA and if it is B, then I will add logic for AB. Once it is done I will clear my stack.

Is there a simpler way to do it? Please advice

Comment: How do the events arrive? Asynchronously? And you use event listeners to handle the events or do they arrive in a socket?

Comment: @JoelWitteveen These 2 events are synchronous. I am using JMS for communication. I am registering for state notification for these events and handling the notification here.

Comment: Is it possible for events to arrive as AA or BB? Or is it guaranteed that they alternate?

Comment: Yes. The events will be either AB or BA. and not AA or BB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is Synchronous and you only can have these to possibilities, you only need one boolean (hasOtherArrived) to do it:

When Event arrives, check if hasOtherArrived is true: if it is execute needed code (depending on which event arrived) and set hasOtherArrived to false. Otherwise set hasOtherArrived to true.

A little schema for AB (the BA case is similar)
[image]

Comment: the problem is I need both events A and B. So, if I use one boolean it will not work. Its like binary. But what I need is pair.

Comment: Thanks. I have one question. When should we set the boolean hasOtherArrived value? My initial value would be false. Then when I encounter event A, I will check if "hasotherArrived" is set to false, then I will set it to true (Indicates sequence is AB). Now when i get event B, I will check if "hasotherArrived" is set to false but as it is true what action do i need to take? Did I miss anything here? Please advice

Comment: I guess now I understood. Here is a code snippet      if (!hasOtherArrived)
         {          
       bInSequence = true;
       System.out.println("Sequence is AB");
       hasOtherArrived = true;          
         }
         else
          hasOtherArrived = false;

Comment: @Rag: yes, when the first event arrives, hasOtherArrived is false and set to true. When the second arrives, hasOtherArrived is true, the sequence is now well defined (either AB or BA, depending on which event arrived) and you can set hasOtherArrived to false to start over again for the next pair.

Answer (score 0):

use a counter . set its value =2;

```
1. in onreceiveEventA : decerement the counter
   if(counter==0){
   // you know that event sequence is BA
    }

2. in onreceiveEventB :decrement the counter
     if(counter==0){
   // you know that event sequence is AB
    }
```

Comment: If the events arrive Asynchronously then this solution can cause race conditions.

Comment: @JoelWitteveen - No. This design is to handle async events. How can I get a race condition here?. I tried this approach in Android. Its working fine. Please tell me what I am missing.

Comment: Event A arrives, immediately after B arrives and decreases the counter by 1 next A decrease the counter and faulty thinks B arrived before A.

Comment: You will have to synchronize on counter.

Comment: Synchronizing on the counter is not enough. If Event A arrives and it cannot obtain the lock in its processor time the events described in my previous comment can still occur.

Comment: seems like I need to relook at the code i implemented somewhere.. @JoelWitteveen - Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since, I do not know exactly how you are getting your input or your use-case, it is not that clear to me what is better for you. here is what I am thinking about:

1. You can use `queue` instead of stack. Since `queue` follow `FIFO` style `First In First Out`. So, no need to reverse the selection like what you are thinking about in `Stack`
2. If you are sure there is only two option then you can define two variable. for example `choice1` and `choice2` where you are storing the first input in `choice1` and the second input in `choice2`.

**Note: this solution will not work if there is more than one choice.**

Comment: The only concern that I have with using stack or queue is overkill of resource for this trivial thing. So, I wanted to ask for a simpler and efficient approach.